# Master/Slave desyncronisation

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

Some manual operations (writes) have been made on SLAVE instead of MASTER resulting in the replication being stopped.

```
Could not execute Delete_rows_v1 event on table xxx.newsletter; 
Can't find record in 'newsletter', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; 
the event's master log master-bin.000061, end_log_pos 30109220
```

I've manually recreated the row which has been deleted on the SLAVE.

Is there a way to **easily** "resume" it without stopping the master, exporting the DB, and starting the whole process again please ? (This happened months ago so the SLAVE is really out of date)

Running MariaDB 10.x
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have corrected the slave drift, you can just "start slave" again, **but**

- You may need to skip some transactions, if they have been manually applied to the slave- you can do that with [`SET GLOBAL sql_slave_skip_counter`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-global-sql-slave-skip-counter.html)
- You probably have other differences between the master and the slave, because of the operations you mentioned or because of the skipping of transactions. In that case, using [pt-table-checksum](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-table-checksum.html) and pt-table-sync can help you resync the slave without having to reload the full contents.

Answer (score 2):

A smaller shell script can help the cause assuming you have catered all the differences between master/slave..

provided you have login path created if not use -uroot -ppass otherwise. Moreover you may need to check output log and need to correct the out of sync tables manually.

> c=`mysql --login-path=lgp   --protocol=TCP -NBe "show status like  'slave_running' " |awk '{print $2}'`
>   echo $c
>   while [ $c == "OFF"  ]
>   do
>   mysql --login-path=lgp   --protocol=TCP -NBe "stop slave"
>   mysql --login-path=lgp   --protocol=TCP -NBe "SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1"
>   mysql --login-path=lgp   --protocol=TCP -NBe "STart SLAVE;do sleep(2);"
>   mysql --login-path=lgp   --protocol=TCP -e "SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G" >>out1.txt
>
> done

Hope it helps